# Qute Dynamically created template not able to understand object data

Tags: quarkus-qute

I am using below code to create a dynamic template -

```
Engine engine = Engine.builder().addDefaults().build();
Template t = engine.parse(" Dear:Your {obj.name}", null, "something");
Body obj = new Body();
obj.name = "ABC";
t.data("obj",obj).render()
```

I expect  Dear:Your ABC as a result of the render. Instead I get, Dear:Your NOT_FOUND

If I do something like below it works as expected -

```
Template t = engine.parse(" Dear:Your {name}", null, "something"); 
t.data("name",name).render()
```

Somehow when qute templates are created with engine.parse, they are not able to understand the object as data.
If I use the same contect with the html file injection as -

```
@Inject
Template something;
something.data("obj",obj).render();
```

This renders as expected. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of going through the documentation (very little available) and bit of source code, I think I finally found the answer.

Only thing I had to do is use the existing engine instance by injecting instead of crating a new one.

Replacing -

```
Engine engine = Engine.builder().addDefaults().build(); with
@Inject
Engine engine;
```

works fine for me.

Just posting here if it helps anyone else in the same boat.